# apollo-angular error // angular Project won't compile

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, apollo, apollo-angular

When trying to compile a project in angular I get the following errors

```
ERROR in node_modules/apollo-angular/Apollo.d.ts(1,100): error TS2305: Module '"/usr/app/node_modules/apollo-client/index"' has no exported member 'ApolloClientOptions'.
node_modules/apollo-angular/Apollo.d.ts(8,27): error TS2315: Type 'ApolloClient' is not generic.
node_modules/apollo-angular/Apollo.d.ts(13,18): error TS2315: Type 'ApolloClient' is not generic.
node_modules/apollo-angular/Apollo.d.ts(14,23): error TS2315: Type 'ApolloClient' is not generic.
```

I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling the modules but I get the same error... can anybody tell me what these errors mean exactly?

I'm using these versions

apollo-angular: 1.0.1,

node: v8.12.0

Comment: apollo-angular needs some dependencies do you install that?

Comment: @Asanka Yes, all the dependencies are installed